Unaligned int64_t Access on x86: Can Concurrent Read/Write Threads Lead to Intermediate State Values?
On an Intel x86 CPU, if an int64_t a is stored at an unaligned address such as 0x7ffbc82f1c7a, and a write thread modifies the value of a, does this require accessing the memory twice due to the unaligned nature? In this scenario, if a read thread accesses the value, is it possible for it to read an intermediate state of the value?
I used mmap as a memory allocator to allocate space and performed a type cast, which led me to encounter this issue. When changing the value from -1 to 153538, my program read -281474976557118 instead. The two's complement of both values are strikingly similar, which makes me suspect that an intermediate state was read.
The two's complement of -1 is: 
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
The two's complement of 153538 is: 
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100101011111000010
The two's complement of -281474976557118 is: 
1111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000100101011111000010

Does anyone know if such behavior is expected on an x86 CPU (OS: Linux 4.19)?
expecting an authoritative statement

Aligned access is atomic. Unaligned access within a cache line is atomic. Unaligned access crossing cache lines is not atomic. As described in the answer there and in the Intel reference manual

Does this answer your question? What's the actual effect of successful unaligned accesses on x86?

Also, since you tagged this question with C++: In C++'s memory model none of this is permitted. You need properly aligned atomics

@Homer512 -- re: "Aligned access is atomic" -- for some unspecified meaning of "atomic" (presumably "won't tear"). It's not "atomic" in the way that the word is used in the C++ standard.

@PeteBecker Yes, in fact the reference manual section 8.1.1 says "Unaligned 16-, 32-, and 64-bit accesses to cached memory that fit within a cache line." The reference does in fact not clarify what access. You could read this as meaning read-modify-write but of course we both know only reading and writing are meant by this

For C++, unaligned memory access is undefined behavior.  Your specific compiler may guarantee an implementation defined behavior.  Or your platform (Intel x86, in this case) may guarantee an architecture defined behavior.

@Homer512 Thanks.  I understand that this approach is not allowed in the C++ memory model. However, I hope to achieve a lock-free data structure using this method in a multithreaded or even multiprocess environment (based on mmap shared). For my use case, as long as it can read either the old or the new value, and not a non-existent value, that's sufficient.

You can always find the next aligned position with std::align

@PeteBecker: yes, "won't tear".  Intel's manual documents asm, and much of what C++ atomic gives you is blocking optimizations like hosting loads out of loops and just using a register.  Also ordering; in x86 asm you get memory_order_acquire for free on loads, release on stores, but not C++'s default of seq_cst.  Intel's and AMD's x86 manuals do of course document the x86-TSO memory model.

@Homer512: Note that Intel gives stronger atomicity guarantees than AMD: AMD allows tearing across any 8-byte boundary, Intel only for cache-line splits.  So AMD's guarantees are the common subset that can be assumed for generic x86-64 software.  (Recent AMD hardware in practice is stronger, as https://rigtorp.se/isatomic/ shows even 32-byte aligned vector stores are in practice atomic, and vendors even document 16-byte aligned load/store as atomic on CPUs with AVX.)

@worldhello: If you want your software to work correctly on old multi-socket AMD K10 Opteron systems, you definitely need 8-byte alignment for 8-byte objects.  Those can tear at 8-byte boundaries when HyperTransport carries cache lines between cores on different sockets.  Otherwise misaligned within a 16-byte or even 32-byte chunk on some more recent AMD CPUs is safe for a std::atomic<uint64_t> * pointing into shared mem, at least as far as atomicity as long as your compiler doesn't do anything weird.  Split across a 64B boundary will always be non-atomic even on Intel.

My answer on the linked duplicate quotes Intel's and AMD's manuals regarding asm; to take full advantage you need to safely get a C++ compiler to make machine code that does potentially-misaligned accesses, perhaps with GNU C typedef std::atomic<uint64_t> unaligned_atomic_u64 __attribute__((aligned(1))) if you want to tell the compiler it's fine; you'll be worrying about sufficient alignment.  Keep in mind that cache-line-split locked (RMW) operations are extremely slow, like system-wide all-cores stall, so slow there's an option to make them trap so devs can find them without perf ctrs.
